# Data fetching from table on website

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I need help on extracting or scrap data from table on webpage. I am using beautiful soup. Unable to extract table with table no. 6. Anyhelp would be appreciated:

All rows data from table - 6 is needed. There are several tables within a single webpage but I need data for only Compliance information don't know how to do it.

URL is given [here](http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber=1&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods=)

My code is given below:

```
link = ["http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber=1&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods="]

for pagenum, links in enumerate(link[start:end]):

  print(links)
  r = requests.get(links)

  time.sleep(random.randint(2,5)) 

  soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

  tree = html.fromstring(str(soup))

  value = []

  data_block = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "bordertb"})

  print (data_block)

  output = []

  for item in data_block:

    table_data = item.find_all("td", {"class": "tabletitle"})[0].table

    value.append([table_data])

    print (value)


  with open("Exhibit_2_EXP_data.tsv", "wb") as outfile:

    outfile = unicodecsv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t")

   outfile.writerow(["Data_Output"])

   for item in value:

     outfile.writerow(item)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The below script should fetch you the content from that table. To make it specific you should start your operation from the previous table (as it has got a unique ID) then using the appropriate method you can reach the content of your desired table. Here is what I did to achieve the same:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber=1&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods="

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.find(id="tblInstallationContacts").find_next_sibling().find_all("tr")[:-5]:
    data = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.find_all("td")]
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks SIM it worked and data is coming in desired format. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Don't forget to tick the grayed out checkmark between the up/down buttons next to my answer to select it as the accepted solution. Take here a look [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks

Comment: Can you please help on separating the Output values of the table based on Span HTML tag so the output would come like 195640
421 *****  for URL http://ec.europa.eu/environment/ets/ohaDetails.do?returnURL=&languageCode=en&accountID=&registryCode=&buttonAction=all&action=&account.registryCode=&accountType=&identifierInReg=&accountHolder=&primaryAuthRep=&installationIdentifier=&installationName=&accountStatus=&permitIdentifier=&complianceStatus=&mainActivityType=-1&searchType=oha&resultList.currentPageNumber=1587&nextList=Next%C2%A0%3E&selectedPeriods=

Comment: Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Done with the issue. Used str.split with str.join